How to use color in log4j only, when writing to a tty?
Our bash scripts use color for log-messages, but only, when stderr is a tty:
if [ -t 2 ]
then
    function log {
        # Use blue color for our messages, when stderr is a terminal
        printf "%(%F %T)T %s \e[1;34m%s\e[1;0m\n" -1 ${0##*/} "$*" >&2
    }

else
    function log {
        printf "%(%F %T)T %s %s\n" -1 ${0##*/} "$*" >&2
    }
fi

We'd like for the logs produced by the Java-programs to also be colored -- but only, when written to a tty. I tried adding the %highlight{} to the pattern of our existing appender:
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stderr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p} %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

but that turns coloring on unconditionally, even when stderr is redirected to a file -- or into a pager.
Can it be told to automatically detect, whether the output is a TTY?
Update: tried adding the noConsoleNoAnsi="true" to the <PatternLayout>, but that seems to disable the highlighting even when stderr is a tty -- probably, because System.console() fails when either one of stdout and stderr is not a tty :\
And in our case, stdout is usually captured.

Since we're invoking the Java programs from scripts anyway (is not everyone?) I added the following code to the invoking bash-script to pass the property:
    [ -t 2 ] && JAVA_SW="$JAVA_SW -DdisableAnsi=false"
...
    java $JAVA_SW com.example.OurClass "$@"

And then modified the <PatternLayout> to honor the property, if set:
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stderr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout disableAnsi="${sys:disableAnsi:-true}"
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p} %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

I still feel, this shouldn't be necessary -- that log4j ought to be able to detect, whether the actual destination is a tty, automatically.
